# How to filter out .svn-base files from DIR command output?

Tags: windows, command-line, svn

I was wondering how I could go about doing the following (in Windows)

I need to examine the total number of characters in the full path to everything in c:\directory and all subdirectories.  Here is the command I was using:

```
dir /b /s c:\directory\ > output.csv
```

/B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

/S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.

The issue is that c:\directory is a SVN checkout and has a ton of .svn-base files that i do not want to see in the output.csv file.   How do I go about filtering output from DIR so I do not see any of these .svn or .svn-base files in output.csv that I am piping the output to?

I tried to use Excel to search the first column in output.csv to select any rows that contain 'svn', but this csv file has well over 30,000 rows in it and that might take awhile to filter everything out if I do it that way.

Is there something similar to grep for windows that I can use to accomplish this?   I downloaded grep GNUWin32 but when I try to use it I get some error about a missing library file.

I also have tried to use the /A-H switch in DIR and for whatever reason I still get the .svn folders in each subdirectory :(   It very well could be I am not using the switch to not show hidden files correctly..

Comment: What version of windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cmd prompt, this should do it:

```
dir /b /s c:\directory\ | Findstr /V /I .svn > output.csv
```

If you are on Windows 7/8 or you have installed Powershell, I would suggest learning it. In Powershell you would do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem . -exclude *.svn -recurse | Select-Object Name | Export-CSV .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution (for the cost of size)

Before dir `svn export` WC into export-dir and eliminate this way .svn dir(s)